# Was abort() not async-signal-safe in glibc versions < 2.27?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I am reading about [signal safety](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) in the manpages, and `abort` is one of the async signal safe functions as required by the POSIX standard.
However, according to the manpages for [abort](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html), it says

> Up until glibc 2.26, if the abort() function caused process
> termination, all open streams were closed and flushed (as with
> fclose(3)).

`fclose` is not listed as async-signal-safe (although `close` is).
Does this mean that `abort` was not async-signal-safe in glibc versions before 2.27?

Another reason why I'm thinking this is that `exit(3)` is not async-signal-safe because it flushes the stdio buffers, which is what `abort` used to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `fclose` is not listed as async-signal-safe (although `close` is). Does this mean that `abort` was not async-signal-safe in glibc versions before 2.27?

Yes, you are correct. `abort` was *not* async-signal-safe in the earlier versions. At a certain stage, it would [try to] `fclose` all open *streams*. And, it will do this from an internal signal handler it sets up.

A given stream could be locked or in an indeterminate state. The TL;DR is that `abort` *was* not async safe because `fclose` was [and is] *not* async safe.

One of the reasons for lack of async safety is that `malloc` et. al. are *not* async safe. Although they wrap access in mutexes, they do *not* mask signals. A process/thread could be doing `set*buf` on a stream that involves doing `realloc`. A call within a signal handler could corrupt the heap and/or crash.

---

It might help to be able to look at the older source. Here is the `glibc` source page:

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html

On that page, we can clone the `glibc` git repository:

```
git clone https://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git
cd glibc
git checkout master
```

This will give us a fairly modern version.

But, with a slight change to the instructions there, we can checkout an earlier version:

```
git checkout release/2.25/master
```

Then, if we look at `stdlib/abort.c`, we see:

```
  /* Now close the streams which also flushes the output the user
     defined handler might has produced.  */
  if (stage == 4)
    {
      ++stage;
      __fcloseall ();
    }
```

In later versions, stage 4 is missing the `__fcloseall` call:

```
  /* Now try to abort using the system specific command.  */
  if (stage == 4)
    {
      ++stage;
      ABORT_INSTRUCTION;
    }
```

---

Here's a [manual] diff of 2.25 to current:

```
--- abort.c 2022-12-11 22:42:33.064470777 -0500
+++ /tmp/abort.c    2022-12-11 22:42:21.106728443 -0500
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-/* Copyright (C) 1991-2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
+/* Copyright (C) 1991-2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This file is part of the GNU C Library.

    The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
@@ -13,7 +13,7 @@

    You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
    License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
-   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */
+   <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

 #include <libc-lock.h>
 #include <signal.h>
@@ -21,6 +21,7 @@
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
+#include <internal-signals.h>

 /* Try to get a machine dependent instruction which will make the
    program crash.  This is used in case everything else fails.  */
@@ -30,11 +31,8 @@
 # define ABORT_INSTRUCTION
 #endif

-#include <libio/libioP.h>
-#define fflush(s) _IO_flush_all_lockp (0)
-
 /* Exported variable to locate abort message in core files etc.  */
-struct abort_msg_s *__abort_msg __attribute__ ((nocommon));
+struct abort_msg_s *__abort_msg;
 libc_hidden_def (__abort_msg)

 /* We must avoid to run in circles.  Therefore we remember how far we
@@ -50,32 +48,24 @@
 abort (void)
 {
   struct sigaction act;
-  sigset_t sigs;

   /* First acquire the lock.  */
   __libc_lock_lock_recursive (lock);

   /* Now it's for sure we are alone.  But recursive calls are possible.  */

-  /* Unlock SIGABRT.  */
+  /* Unblock SIGABRT.  */
   if (stage == 0)
     {
       ++stage;
-      if (__sigemptyset (&sigs) == 0 &&
-     __sigaddset (&sigs, SIGABRT) == 0)
-   __sigprocmask (SIG_UNBLOCK, &sigs, (sigset_t *) NULL);
-    }
-
-  /* Flush all streams.  We cannot close them now because the user
-     might have registered a handler for SIGABRT.  */
-  if (stage == 1)
-    {
-      ++stage;
-      fflush (NULL);
+      internal_sigset_t sigs;
+      internal_sigemptyset (&sigs);
+      internal_sigaddset (&sigs, SIGABRT);
+      internal_sigprocmask (SIG_UNBLOCK, &sigs, NULL);
     }

   /* Send signal which possibly calls a user handler.  */
-  if (stage == 2)
+  if (stage == 1)
     {
       /* This stage is special: we must allow repeated calls of
     `abort' when a user defined handler for SIGABRT is installed.
@@ -93,7 +83,7 @@
     }

   /* There was a handler installed.  Now remove it.  */
-  if (stage == 3)
+  if (stage == 2)
     {
       ++stage;
       memset (&act, '\0', sizeof (struct sigaction));
@@ -103,30 +93,22 @@
       __sigaction (SIGABRT, &act, NULL);
     }

-  /* Now close the streams which also flushes the output the user
-     defined handler might has produced.  */
-  if (stage == 4)
-    {
-      ++stage;
-      __fcloseall ();
-    }
-
   /* Try again.  */
-  if (stage == 5)
+  if (stage == 3)
     {
       ++stage;
       raise (SIGABRT);
     }

   /* Now try to abort using the system specific command.  */
-  if (stage == 6)
+  if (stage == 4)
     {
       ++stage;
       ABORT_INSTRUCTION;
     }

   /* If we can't signal ourselves and the abort instruction failed, exit.  */
-  if (stage == 7)
+  if (stage == 5)
     {
       ++stage;
       _exit (127);
```