# Getting assert message in SIGABRT handler

Tags: c, signals, assert

I catch problems with this code:

```
void handler (int sig) {
    // write error information with a stack trace to disk
}

void set_crash_signals () {
    signal(SIGSEGV, handler);
    signal(SIGABRT, handler);
    signal(SIGFPE, handler);
}
```

Is there a way to get the assert message in the SIGABRT handler?
Is there some other trick I could use?

Comment: You can’t. The assert message, if present, is printed to the stderr and not stored.

Comment: Also, you can _not_ use `assert` in a signal handler because it does `*printf` and `fflush` which are _not_ async-signal-safe. See my answer: [Was abort() not async-signal-safe in glibc versions < 2.27?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74766438/5382650) for some details. Also, see the man page: [signal-safety](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Comment: You _might_ be able to use `LD_PRELOAD` and intercept the [linux, e.g.] `__assert_fail` function in `glibc`, using `dlopen/dlsym` _before_ it actually does the `abort()` call. This will work for any `assert` that _your_ code does (but, not for `assert` calls that `glibc` itself does [internally]). But, _not_ from the signal handler after the fact. Or, with `cpp` macros, `#define __assert_fail my_assert_fail` so you don't need to use `dl*` for _your_ code.

Comment: Many thanks or you comments. This was enlightening.

Comment: _If_ you control the source, just don't use `assert` but write your own: `#define johan_assert(_expr) do { if (! (_expr)) johan_assert_fail(#_expr,__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__); } while (0)` Then, define your own function somewhere. You can have _it_ do _whatever_ you want.